# error while using Numpy Random function (np.random.random_integers)

Tags: numpy-random

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Uzr6.png)

Error while using numpy random function,
it shows int object not callable
please suggest alternative

Answer (score 2):

You missed out on the second comma while passing arguments to `np.random.random_integers` (here: (`100(3,4))`), so it assumes 100 is a function to which you're passing arguments 3 and 4, which is not the case as 100 is an integer.

Change

```py
np.random.random_integers(50, 100(3,4))
```

to

```py
np.random.random_integers(50, 100, (3, 4))
```

Comment: Thanx Shreya 

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> xx=np.random.random_integers(50,100(3,4))
> ```
>
> please suggest alternative

As an alternative I suggest to insert the missing comma:

```
xx = np.random.random_integers(50, 100, (3, 4))
```

Comment: Thanx Ramai 